unable to click on webelement with selenium ActionsChain or javascript click as it refreshes the page and gives StaleElementReferenceError
I'm trying to close a cookie consent pop-up on a site https://www.meinschiff.com/. I used selenium webdriver for chrome to find the close and accept div element and click on whichever is found first. If I manually choose deny button, then it is closed but it hangs with a loading of another layer. The element's parent's parent div element with id="blur" acts as an ever loading overlay. The code fetches the accept button first and clicks on it but it refreshes the page giving StaleElementReference error. The clicks work perfectly when I open the site in a normal chrome browser.
I want to click accept button and close the pop up.
My code:
          div_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 
         5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "div")))
     for div_element in div_elements:
        try:
            element_html = div_element.get_attribute("outerHTML")
            div_element_attrs = BeautifulSoup(element_html, "lxml").div.attrs
            # class_attr = div_element.get_attribute('class')
            # title_attr = div_element.get_attribute('title')
            value_attr = div_element.get_attribute('value')
            popup_div = False
            for key in div_element_attrs.keys():
                if any(keyword in (div_element.get_attribute(key) or '').lower() 
                     for keyword in close_keywords) or \
                    (value_attr is not None and value_attr.lower() == 'false'):
                    print("closing div pop-up...")
                    popup_div = True
                    break
                else:
                    if any(keyword in (div_element.get_attribute(key) or 
                        '').lower() for keyword in accept_keywords) or \
                        (value_attr is not None and value_attr.lower() == 'false'):
                        print("accepting div pop-up...")
                        popup_div = True
                        break
            if popup_div: 
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(div_element).click().perform()
                time.sleep(2)
                if div_element.is_displayed():
                    print("div element not closed")
                    return False
                else:
                    print("div element closed")
                    return True
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
             print(f"Div Element click intercepted: 
             {div_element.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")
            continue
        except Exception as e:
             print(f"Error processing div element: {e}")
            continue

I have also tried javascript click with:
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", div_element)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", div_element)

and wait for element to be clickable and it results in same behavior:
 clickable_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 
           10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(div_element)) 
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(clickable_element).click().perform()


you're overcomplicating things here... you don't need to iterate over all s on the page.  Just use a standard webdriverwait to locate the button you want to click and click it.  Then the popup will go away.  (usually after setting a cookie, so add a little bit of sleep afterwards)

I understand what you are saying browsermator. I have to create a general popup blocker for 100s of sites. So, I can't use a proper xpath for each site. There are some sites that have popup interacting buttons as div with class or role as button. It has slowed down my code but it's needed for some sites. I have temporarily solved the issue with chrome_options prefs setting as "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1 to allow cookies. Now, I still get StaleElementReferenceError but the button is clickable now and the pop up gets closed.

I think the only general case you might be able to deal with would be something that catches StaleElement and ClickIntercepted errors.  Targeting the button(s) would still be an issue, though... you could possible try to interpret the ClickIntercepted error as it will list the element that would have intercepted the click.

I don't know if i have truly understand your post but like @browsermator say's, it seem's to be a timing issue.
You can use Implicit Waits : Selenium-python Documentation

5.2. Implicit Waits An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or
elements) not immediately available. The default setting is 0 (zero).
Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver
object.
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")


The script below launch the driver, set an implicit waits of 10 seconds, go to meinschiff webpage , deny cookie and print the slogan of meinschiff :
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) 

# Open the website
driver.get('https://www.meinschiff.com/')

try:
    # Close and refuse cookies
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "privacy_pref_optout").click()
    
    # Print the slogan in the webpage 
    slogan = driver.find_element(By.ID, "html")
    print(slogan.text)
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

I hope it will help you. Feel free to tell us if your issu is solved.

Thanks Arthur. I'll try implicitly_wait in my code. I have temporarily solved the issue with chrome_options prefs setting as "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1 to allow cookies. Now, I still get StaleElementReferenceError but the button is clickable now and the pop up gets closed.

Solution:
I have set allow cookies to True in the selenium chrome options prefs settings and now the button is clickable and closes the popup. I'm still getting StaleElementReferenceError because the page gets refreshed and found element is erased from the driver.
 chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1})

